# change the default tab in snipMate

Tags: vim, snipmate

I have been reading the documentation for a while but I can't seem to find any information on how to change the default key for completion in snipMate.

Here is the documentation. https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/doc/snipMate.txt
Did I overlook something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done via two variables; it doesn't seem to be documented, but it's done in `after/plugin/snipMate.vim`. To override, redefine these variables before the plugin is sourced, e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:let g:snips_trigger_key = '<tab>'
:let g:snips_trigger_key_backwards = '<s-tab>'
```

Answer (score 8):

In `:help SnipMate-mappings`

> The mappings SnipMate uses can be customized with the :map commands.For
>       example, to change the key that triggers snippets and moves to the next tab stop, >
>
> ```
>     :imap <C-J> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
>     :smap <C-J> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
> ```

Comment: When I use this, `<C-J>` inserts the text `<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger`

Answer (score 2):

It is actually documented:

```
:help snipMate-remap
```